# How to get random value from specific ranges of dictionary content

Tags: c#, dictionary, random

If this way I can get random value from given range:

```
 int r = ran.Next(1, 4); 
 string v;
 if (dict.TryGetValue(r, out v))
 {
    ///...
 }
```

how to properly get random value of `<int, string>` dictionary content from specific range, for example only from 4 to 6 and 1 and 2 and avoid look for 3:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
    { 1, "word1" },
    { 2, "word2" },
    { 3, "word3" },
    { 4, "word4" },
    { 5, "word5" },
    { 6, "word6" }
};
```

Comment: How do you guarantee that all values in the range exist in the `Dictionary` and if you can, why not just use an `array` / `List` to store it instead of a `Dictionary`

Comment: @ Vikhram Hello, guaranteed  because it is not an updated list. and, yes with List or Array it is simple and useful, but I'm wondering about dictionary <int, string> if it is possible

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a solution using an extension method:

```
public static class RandomExtensions
{
    public static int NextWithinRange(this Random random, params Range[] ranges)
    {
        if (ranges.Length > 0)
        {
            Range range = ranges[random.Next(0, ranges.Length)];
            return random.Next(range.MinValue, range.MaxValue + 1);
        }

        return random.Next();
    }

    public class Range
    {
        public int MinValue { get; set; }
        public int MaxValue { get; set; }

        public Range(int minValue, int maxValue)
        {
            MinValue = minValue;
            MaxValue = maxValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
int r = ran.NextWithinRange(new Range(1, 2), new Range(4, 6));
string v;
if (dict.TryGetValue(r, out v))
{
    ///...
}
```

---

Here's a solution using LINQ:

```
var rand = new Random();

// create a new dictionary, filtering out any unwanted keys within range(s)
Dictionary<int, string> filteredDict =
    dict.Where(pair => (pair.Key >= 1 && pair.Key <= 2)
                    || (pair.Key >= 4 && pair.Key <= 6))
        .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);

// get a random entry from the filtered dictionary
KeyValuePair<int, string> entry = filteredDict.ElementAt(rand.Next(0, filteredDict.Count));

// get random entry's value
string value = entry.Value;
```

EDIT: thanks @Kyle for pointing out the potential `ArgumentOutOfRange` exception in my initial post.

Comment: This can fail if the dictionary contains the excluded keys, since the random number selected may be greater than the number of remaining key-value pairs.  This will cause `ElementAt` to throw an `ArgumentOutOfRange` exception.

Answer (score 0):

Create HashSet with excluded values then

```
HashSet<int> excludedValues = ....
List<int> values = dict.Where(x=> excludedValues.Contains(x.Key) == false).Select(x=>x.Key).ToList();

int index = rand.Next(1, values.Count);
string value = dict[index];
```

This way you are not limited to excluding value 3. You can put anything in this collection. If your collections are big you should use hashset which is much faster then List.

Answer (score 0):

In general there are a couple of functions available in `LINQ` namely [IEnumerable.Skip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx) and [IEnumerable.Take](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx)

These functions can be used to get a slice of any `IEnumerable`. Remember that `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is also an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`

So to access a random element between the 4th and 10th element.

```
var rand = new Random();
dict.Skip(3).Take(6 /* 10 - 4 */).ElementAt(rand.Next(6 /* 10 - 4 */)
```

Now do remember that the sequence is not necessarily sorted or sequenced by the key or in any predictable way. You might have to use `OrderBy` to traverse the dictionary in the sequence of your choice.

If you want to do these things numerous times between the dictionary getting updated, then you can simply access `dict.Keys.OrderBy().ToList()` and then access this `List` using the same `Skip().Take().ElementAt()` or directly with index manipulations. This will avoid re-enumerating the same dictionary multiple times

Answer (score 0):

You can collect all the values which can be taken and then choose random one from them:

```
   private static Random s_Random = new Random(); 

   ...

   var values = dict
      .Where(pair => pair.Key >= 4 && pair.Key <= 6 || // conditions on key
                     pair.Key >= 1 && pair.Key <= 2)
      .ToArray();

   var result = values[s_Random.Next(values.Length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

With this solution you can get a random value within specified ranges without having to iterate the dictionary first.

```
void Main()
{
    Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>()
    {
        { 1, "word1" },
        { 2, "word2" },
        { 3, "word3" },
        { 4, "word4" },
        { 5, "word5" },
        { 6, "word6" }
    };
    var randomizer = new Random();
    GetRandomValue(dict, randomizer, new Range(4, 6), new Range(1,2)).Dump();
}

public TValue GetRandomValue<TValue>(IDictionary<int, TValue> dic, Random randomizer, params Range[] ranges)
{
    var range = ranges[randomizer.Next(0, ranges.Length)];
    var key = randomizer.Next(range.From, range.To + 1);
    return dic[key];
}

public class Range
{
    public Range(int @from, int to)
    {
        From = @from;
        To = to;
    }
    public int From {get;set;}
    public int To {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly is needed, the easiest might be to specify the possible numbers:

```
int[] a { 1, 2, 4, 5, 6 };

int r = a[ran.Next(a.Length)];
```

or

```
int r = ran.Next(1, 6); 

if (r == 3) r = 6;
```